# How to revert a buffer using the "g" shortcut

Tags: key-bindings, dired, revert-buffer

I can refresh my `dired` buffer using `M-x revert-buffer`

and I've seen multiple places that I can do this more easily using `g` but don't understand how that would be run. Does it mean `M-x g` or running `g <RET>` somehow?

Searched around but haven't figured out what basic trick I'm missing so thanks for the help.

Comment: It very literally means type `g`.  Which presumably you have already tried, but do not think it's working?  What are you expecting to see, which you are not seeing from typing `g` ?

Comment: yeah I thought I created a subdirectory, that i wasn't seeing but I'll go back and check the whole thing again. Thanks for confirming, just thought commands had to be either `C-` or `M-` but clearly not

Comment: It's common for modes that don't involve directly editing text, like `dired`, `magit`, `info` etc., to bind 'naked' keys to commands. This should be clear from the documentation: if you need to press Meta/Alt, or Control, the documentation will specify that explicitly: `M-g` and `C-g`, for example. If the documentation refers to a single key (i.e., `g`) for a command, you should just press that key.

Comment: thanks both. tried `g` again and yeah of course it works.

Comment: "just thought commands had to be either C- or M- but clearly not" -- Indeed. FYI even when you are entering text, each letter you insert is the result of a command bound to the associated key (generally `self-insert-command`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can see what command a key sequence is bound to by using 'M-x describe-key' (normally bound to 'C-h k').

Switching to a dired buffer and running C-h k gives an extensive help text.  The start is:

```
g runs the command revert-buffer (found in dired-mode-map), which is                                                                                                                                               
an interactive compiled Lisp function in ‘files.el’.                                                                                                                                                               

It is bound to g, <menu-bar> <immediate> <revert-buffer>, <menu-bar>                                                                                                                                               
<file> <revert-buffer>.
```

From this we learn that g is bound to 'revert-buffer' and the binding is in 'dired-mode-map'.